# React-redux state changes but no re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I currently have a single page app that logs a user in and after login should re-render to the appropriate page. On dev tools I see the state change but I have to manually refresh the page. The page re-render on the basis of seeing a current user exists. If there is a current user it should return a different component. Here is the code snippet below.

So far ive double checked to make sure my reducer is not mutating the state and is in fact returning the correct newState. My state is also normalized correctly and the component below is correctly watching the slice of state that changes.

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      debugger 
    }

    render () {
      debugger 
      const sessionLinks = () => (
        <div className="login-signup">
          <div className="navhead">
         <div className="butterflyr">butterflyr</div>
          <img className="butterfree" src={window.butterFree}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LogInFormContainer}/>
          </div>     
          <SignUpFormContainer/> 
        </div>
      );
      const homePage = () => (
        <hgroup className="header-group">
          <NavBar  currentUser={this.props.currentUser} logout={this.props.logout}></NavBar>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ForFun}/>
        </hgroup>
      )
      return ( 
        <div>{this.props.currentUser ? homePage() : sessionLinks()}</div>
      )
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi there, please can you share snippet of codes on how the Greetings component is being used?

Comment: could you post your container that's connecting state to props?